# How to make a String.format flag with a variable inside

Tags: java, string.format

I need to format a numeric `String` to be of length `k`, which is the length of a parameter `String`. How do I get `String.format()` to use a flag like `"%0kd"`?

Edit: I realise String.format() does not support what I need. A better question is how to get it.

Comment: Adding input and expected output would clear lot of things

Comment: Can you show a couple of concrete input and output examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
int k = 5;
System.out.println(String.format("%0" + k + "d", 10));
```

It prints:

> 00010